# Import d.ts definitions from specific node_modules package

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, node-modules, shim

I have vue2 + vuetify + typescript starter app. It has `shims-vuetify.d.ts` file with the following content:

```
declare module 'vuetify/lib/framework' {
  import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
  export default Vuetify
}
```

Then it's imported in `/plugins/vuetify.ts` file like that:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
})
```

It works just fine.

My goal is to extend some vuetify component in typescript. For that I'm importing the typescript source code from `vuetify/src/` (not the js-code from `vuetify/lib`):

```
import VAutocomplete from 'vuetify/src/components/VAutocomplete'

export default VAutocomplete.extend({
  ...my stuff..
})
```

It works, but typescript throws a lot of errors during compilation.

It does not see the `node_modules/vuetify/src/globals.d.ts` file.

The question is: how to point typescript to use this declaration file?

I guess the right way is to create `shims-vuetify-src.d.ts` file and refer to `globals.d.ts` there somehow, but for now I was not able to do that correctly.